# Did Peter Parker (Andrew Garfield rendition) contribute, unintentionally and unwittingly, to Gwen's death?

Tags: marvel, the-amazing-spider-man-2

Did Peter Parker (Andrew Garfield rendition, in *The Amazing Spider-Man 2*) contribute, unintentionally and unwittingly, to Gwen's death?

Using physics and physical laws as proof, we know we can use the case of bungee jumping. We know that it stretches and that even a slight miscalculation would lead to severe injuries, if not death.

Peter has shot webs many times, which means that he knows their traveling speed. He should have known this. There was not enough time for the web to stretch the distance it needs before going back up (I think the physics term is called recoil). Since he saw Gwen falling, he could have compared the speed at which she was falling to the speed of his own webs, and concluded that he needed to jump. Jumping and falling feet first is faster than falling on your stomach or your back because there is less resistance.

Comment: Or he could have simply seen his girlfriend falling to her death and lost the ability to think rationally.

Comment: Your action always have an impact with someone. So yes he contribute unintentionally and unwittingly to Gwen's death. Like if he had remember Electro's name, or if he is stronger, or he give his friend some blood,... Gwen will not die.

Answer (score 7):

### "Film production" answer

In the comics, Gwen Stacy clearly dies of whiplash, although if you read it too fast you may have to go back to the exact panel to notice the "SNAP" onomatopoeia.

In the movie, it was supposed to happen the same way, but test audiences didn't"get it", which is why the filmmakers added Gwen hitting her head on the floor.

> **And the fact that he *almost* saves her.**
>
> Mark Webb (director): [...] The other thing I had to adjust: he webs her and, originally, she didn't hit the ground. She just bounced and her neck was supposed to break. But, what was interesting was people, when they watched that, the web represents salvation to people. **They did not understand or believe or were not willing to accept that she had died -- which is how it was done in the comics. So, we had to add a moment where there's an impact wound.** And then people understood what it meant.
>
> <sub>[*Director Marc Webb Talks About the Shocking Ending to ‘The Amazing Spider-Man 2′*](https://screencrush.com/amazing-spider-man-2-ending/)</sub>

### "People" answer

> Since he saw Gwen falling, he could have compared the speed at which she was falling to the speed of his own webs, and concluded that he needed to jump.

You, I wouldn't know, but personally, if I was used to catching people mid-air with throwable webs and one of my loved ones was to fall off a tower, my immediate reaction wouldn't be to do physics, however relevant that may be.